# Calculating how many acres fall within each 1 square mile section?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, vector-grid

I am using ArcMap. I have a polygon shapefile of parcels that receive surface water from a water district. I also have a polygon shapefile of section boundaries. I want to calculate how many acres fall within each section (1 square mile). I also want to set my symbology to represent how many acres that receive water are in each section. Should be 0-640.

I've tried "Near" and "Intersect"

Comment: I've tried "Near" and "Intersect". I was hoping that it would give me a field with a sum of acreage per field. I completely forgot how to do this.

Comment: Make Feature layer with ratio on acerage field - Intersect. Or Intersect - Summary statistics - Join. Depending on what data/attributes you have. And maybe Field Calculator after Intersect